# Tkinter and encryption

Tags: python, tkinter, encryption

Hello stack overflow members, i have been creating an encryption app with tinter using the code below. I am creating the ability to turn normal word to encryption code and encrytion code back to words.

```
import tkinter as tk
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

def encrypter():
    key1 = 'u8RAvUKIPE3w3VLklEqXv4466uCeEvlKxCvdvEjxDUs='
    f = Fernet(key1)
    message = word.get()
    x = message.encode()
    encryption = f.encrypted(x)
    encrypted.insert(0, encryption)
def decrypter():
    key1 = 'u8RAvUKIPE3w3VLklEqXv4466uCeEvlKxCvdvEjxDUs='
    f = Fernet(key1)
    message2 = encrypt.get()
    decryption = f.decrypt(message2)
    decrypt.insert(0, decryption)
def keycreator():
    key1 = Fernet.generate_key()
    key.insert(0, key1)


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Encrypter/Decrypter")

frame = tk.Frame(master=window, width=500, height=500)
frame.pack()

label1 = tk.Label(master=frame, text = 'Word')
label1.place(x = 10, y = 5)

word = tk.Entry(master=frame)
word.place(x=0,y=25)

btn_convert_encrypt = tk.Button(master=frame, text = "\N{DOWNWARDS BLACK ARROW}", command = decrypter())
btn_convert_encrypt.place(x=40,y=50)

label2 = tk.Label(master=frame, text = 'Encrypted')
label2.place(x = 10, y= 80)

encrypted = tk.Entry(master=frame)
encrypted.place(x = 0, y = 100)

label3 = tk.Label(master=frame, text = 'Encrypted')
label3.place(x = 250, y= 5)

encrypt = tk.Entry(master=frame)
encrypt.place(x=250,y= 25)

btn_convert_decrypt = tk.Button(master=frame, text = "\N{DOWNWARDS BLACK ARROW}", command=encrypter())
btn_convert_decrypt.place(x=290,y=50)

label4 = tk.Label(master=frame, text = 'Word')
label4.place(x = 250, y = 80)

decrypt = tk.Entry(master=frame)
decrypt.place(x = 250, y = 100)

label5 = tk.Label(master=frame, text = 'Key')
label5.place(x = 170, y = 130)

key = tk.Entry(master=frame)
key.place(x = 125, y = 150)

btn_randmize = tk.Button(master=frame, text = "Randmize", command=keycreator)
btn_randmize.place(x = 150, y= 175)

window.mainloop()
```

This code is giving me a name error on line 14 where it said encrypt is not defined. Can anyone help?

Comment: No as it is accessing the encrypted entry widget

Comment: The issue is on `command=decrypter()` which execute `enrypter()` immediately and at this time `encrypt` is not defined yet.  It should be `command=decrypter` instead. Same on `command=encrypter()`.

Answer (score 1):

There were a few mistakes in the code:

1. On line 9: it should be `f.encrypt(x)` instead of `f.encrypted(x)`
2. Both your keys should be in byte format: `key1 = b'u8RAvUKIPE3w3VLklEqXv4466uCeEvlKxCvdvEjxDUs='`
3. As @acw1668 mentioned, your buttons should not call the function: it should be `command=encrypter` and `command=decrypter` instead of `command=encrypter()` and `command=decrypter()` respectively.
4. You interchanged the locations for `command=encrypter` and `command=decrypter`: each should be in the other's place.
5. Also your random key generator didn't update the "actual" key because `key1` was a local variable, so your output didn't change: I changed key1 to a global variable to change the output.

Everything else looks good, I tested it out and it is a neat little program.

Here's the fully edited code:

```
import tkinter as tk

from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

key1 = b'u8RAvUKIPE3w3VLklEqXv4466uCeEvlKxCvdvEjxDUs='


def encrypter():
    f = Fernet(key1)
    message = word.get()
    x = message.encode()
    encryption = f.encrypt(x)
    encrypted.delete(0, tk.END)  # clear the entry field
    encrypted.insert(0, encryption)


def decrypter():
    f = Fernet(key1)
    message2 = encrypt.get()
    decryption = f.decrypt(message2.encode())
    decrypt.delete(0, tk.END)  # clear the entry field
    decrypt.insert(0, decryption)


def keycreator():
    global key1
    key1 = Fernet.generate_key()
    key.insert(0, key1)


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Encrypter/Decrypter")

frame = tk.Frame(master=window, width=500, height=500)
frame.pack()

label1 = tk.Label(master=frame, text='Word')
label1.place(x=10, y=5)

word = tk.Entry(master=frame)
word.place(x=0, y=25)

btn_convert_encrypt = tk.Button(master=frame, text="\N{DOWNWARDS BLACK ARROW}", command=encrypter)
btn_convert_encrypt.place(x=40, y=50)

label2 = tk.Label(master=frame, text='Encrypted')
label2.place(x=10, y=80)

encrypted = tk.Entry(master=frame)
encrypted.place(x=0, y=100)

label3 = tk.Label(master=frame, text='Encrypted')
label3.place(x=250, y=5)

encrypt = tk.Entry(master=frame)
encrypt.place(x=250, y=25)

btn_convert_decrypt = tk.Button(master=frame, text="\N{DOWNWARDS BLACK ARROW}", command=decrypter)
btn_convert_decrypt.place(x=290, y=50)

label4 = tk.Label(master=frame, text='Word')
label4.place(x=250, y=80)

decrypt = tk.Entry(master=frame)
decrypt.place(x=250, y=100)

label5 = tk.Label(master=frame, text='Key')
label5.place(x=170, y=130)

key = tk.Entry(master=frame)
key.place(x=125, y=150)

btn_randmize = tk.Button(master=frame, text="Randmize", command=keycreator)
btn_randmize.place(x=150, y=175)

window.mainloop()
```